# Percentage Complete on Sharepoint List when answers are text, updating to the number of relevant columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have 9 columns in a sharepoint, each one representing a type of check.  I want a column after that calculates the percentage of checks that are clear.  Not all checks are applicable to check record so if their value is "N/A" I don't want them to be included in the calculation.

For the purposes of the formula you can call them "Col1" to "Col9"

The three possible choices in the column are:

- Pending
- Passed
- N/A

So if all 9 checks are relevant they will begin as Pending.  If 6 change to passed then the formula would return a value of 67% clear.

If any of the columns are set to N/A then they should not be included.  So if 1 column is set to N/A, 4 are set to pending, 4 are set to Passed then the formula should return 50%

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thank you for your question.
I am currently looking into this issue and will give you an update as soon as possible.
Thank you for your understanding and support.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved your requirement by creating calculated column（the result of implementation is below）.

[image]
Here are steps:

1.I created 3 choice columns, they have three options Pending, Passed, N/A. (N/A does not participate in the calculation ratio)

2.I created a calculated column using the following formula（ Show as percentage）:

```
=(IF(choice1="Pased",1,0)+IF(choice2="Pased",1,0)+IF(choice3="Pased",1, 0))/(IF(choice1="Pased",1,0)+IF(choice1="Pending",1,0)+IF(choice2="Pased",1,0)++IF(choice2=" Pending",1,0)+IF(choice3="Pased",1,0)+IF(choice3="Pending",1,0))
```

[image]

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Whether the answer helps you?  If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.                                                                                 
***********************************
If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.